# Controller concern constant not being loaded by model concern in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, zeitwerk

Legacy rails app that's been upgraded to v6.0.5.1 - Zeitwerk enabled

I have a controller concern. I.e.

```
# /app/controllers/concerns/example.rb
module Example
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  CONSTANT = [1, 2, 3].freeze
end
```

and a model concern that works as followers

```
# /app/models/concerns/model/exampleable.rb
module Model::Exampleable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    BUILD_ENUM = -> (arr) { arr.each_with_object({}).with_index { |(el, accu), index| accu.merge!({ el.to_sym => index }) } }.freeze

  included do
    enum random_enum: BUILD_ENUM[Example::CONSTANT]
  end
end
```

in my `application.rb`

```
    config.eager_load_paths += %W[
      #{config.root}/app/models/concerns
      #{config.root}/app/controllers/concerns
    ]
```

Everything works fine in development + testing. I've read over the [Rails 6 Autoloading docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) a few times. I cannot figure out what rules I am violating and why it is unable to find the other module. The error I am getting is:

`` app/models/concerns/model/exampleable.rb:8:in `block in <module:Exampleable>': uninitialized constant Example::CONSTANT (NameError) ``

Comment: `/app/models/concerns` and `/app/controllers/concerns` have been both been auto-loading and eager-loading root paths since Rails 4 or so and adding them again isn't going to fix the problem. The issue is most likely something else like a lack of code parity between dev and production.

Comment: This usage is kind of strange too. Typically you would extend `Model::Exampleable` with `Example` so that you're using its constants/methods instead of resolving  them from the outside. If you're doing so at least be explicit and use `::Example::CONSTANT`.

Comment: @max Agree on strange usage. I've fixed the issue by moving the constant elsewhere as it didn't really belong in the controller concern _anyway_. However, I'm still quite confused as to how it's unable to find the constant, even without specifying ::Example as a root lookup. I've checked it's not a naming collision of any sort & when ```Model::Exampleable``` doesn't reference ```Example::CONSTANT``` everything loads fine & as expected.

Comment: Could you post the actual code rather than (I assume) a sanitised version of it? Might be a subtle differene that explains things.

Comment: The error indicates that `Example` is being autoloaded as expected, but it is not defining a `CONSTANT` constant in it. Zeitwerk autoloads `Example`, the existence of `CONSTANT` depends on the source code in `example.rb`. So my hunch is that this is not related to autoloading, and it is probably a programming error. Actual code would help spotting a possible missing detail as @MattGibson said.